# Communicating with a directive instance in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with an isolate scope being rendered inside the template of an outer directive.

I want to send a notification message to the child directive to have it cancel a timer. How can I do this idiomatically?

Will `scope.$broadcast` do this for me even though the child scope is isolate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation for scope.$broadcast:

> Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

So it will perfectly work in your case. Note, that despite of being isolated the scope of the inner directive is still *child* scope of the outer. Isolated just means that this scope doesn't inherit prototypically, however its `$parent` points to the real parent scope. so $broadcast will work in this case of course.

Here is a little example I set up to test it:

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OoUqgV8oRofakXVf2OZv?p=preview